# Cross-platform Video/Audio codec

Tags: .net

I'm looking for a dotNet Audio/Video codec which should work on different platforms like Windows/Linux/(later)iOS/(later)Android. Because of all these platforms i can't use DirectShow ( Windows only ) and already looked for some codecs which are open source.

All of them ( like H.323 ) are written in C++ and i need it in dotNet ( C# ) because we are working with mono in the project. Writing a C++/CLI wrapper seems to be a huge work because thoose codecs are huge.

Has anyone does something like this ever before? Are there any video codecs or commercial solutions on the WWW ( found none )?

Comment: Do you want to encode and decode on all those platforms?

Comment: @NevilleK iOS and Android should only decode, the other platforms ( Linux, Windows ) should also encode. Do you know a library?

Comment: You are looking for a white elephant.  Library and tool recommendations are not on topic here.

Comment: @HansPassant Well its a very difficult topic and you are right i dont want to to all the work but i fear i have to. But i wanted to ask if anyone knows how i can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if tools are off topic, there is a question behind the question, which is: "How do I create a codec if there aren't any C# codec for format X."

I can give a tip that will help you finding really quickly several sources and project to help you progressing:

- Java. Cross-platform tools come with cross-platform language. Search for Java projects, especially on open source hosting platforms. Java is similar to C#, so even for a beginner, porting a code can be done in some hours. Use some translation tools. Apart from an obsession for customized byte buffers, and absence of delegates, it's rather similar.
- Observe. Use one of the three or four major decompilers, and examine the structure of existing DLLs or commercial products. Focus on platforms with managed code like Silverlight or Windows Phone.
- Keyword. Codecs are using very specific technologies in their algorithms. Memorize class names that come often, so that typing them in a search engine will lead you directly to project that focus more and more on what you exactly need.